# How to label a cluster based on the first Message in splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I am trying to achieve below functionality

Generate a `timechart` showing the number of different errors occurring in a server

This I can achieve using below query

```
  index = "my_host" LogLevel=ERROR
  | eval Message=mvindex(field1,1) 
  | timechart count(LogLevel) BY Message
```

This generates a graph like below

[image: Query Without Cluster]

Which is working as expected, now the issue is when I try to cluster the message

```
index = "my_host" LogLevel=ERROR
  | eval Message=mvindex(field1,1) 
  | eval Message=mvindex(field1,1) | cluster t=0.2 field=Message showcount=true labelonly=true | timechart count(LogLevel) BY cluster_label
```

[image: Query with cluster]

The graph is exactly as expected, my challenge is now how to label as label `[1, 2, 3, 4, ...]` isnt user friendly

Is it possible to change this label to the Message field but still group by cluster_label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to correlate the Message field to the cluster_label field and then use the new field in the `timechart` command.  I was able to do it this like this:

```
index = "my_host" LogLevel=ERROR
| eval Message=mvindex(field1,1) 
| eval Message=mvindex(field1,1) 
| cluster t=0.2 field=Message showcount=true labelonly=true 
| bin span=30m _time
| stats count, first(Message) as CL by cluster_label, _time
| timechart max(count) BY CL
```

The `stats` command is needed to get the first Message for each cluster_label and `bin` is needed to group events by _time so `timechart` will work properly.  Choose the span in the `bin` command to match your time window.
One detriment of this method is the `timechart` command cannot automatically select a span since that was done by `bin`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I changed the span to 10s and it worked as expected